# Как завершить цикл без break? JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let password;
let value = "login";
let tries = 5;
while (password != value) {
  password = prompt("Please, password");
  tries = tries - 1
  if (password === value) {
    alert("Welcome");
    continue
  }
  alert(`${tries} left`);
  if (tries === 0) {
    alert('You spent all tries, come back in 5 min');
    false

  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Вы вводите неправильный пароль 5 раз, после фразы 'You spent all tries, come back in 5 min' цикл должен завершится. ЕТО НАДО СДЕЛАТЬ НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЯ BREAK

Comment: С какой целью? (почему не использовать для прерывания цикла то, что именно для этого и предназначено?)

Comment: `while (password != value && tries)` — 0 в логическом контексте будет false.

Comment: Эм.. А зачем делать такое в цикле?

Answer (score 4):

```
  if (tries === 0) {
    alert('You spent all tries, come back in 5 min');
    password = value;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый очевидный вариант ответа уже есть, еще можно еще вот так:

```
throw new Error();
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let password;
let value = "login";
let tries = 5;

[...new Array(tries)].some(()=>{
    password = prompt("Please, password");
    return password === value;
})
```

Comment: Да еще короче `[...'tries']`

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg ))